# How do I access a nested link using Watir webdriver

Tags: html, selenium, watir-webdriver

I am having a hard time accessing elements on a webpage for automated testing. The page is written in nested li elements with a link buried under those elements. Here is an example..

```
<div class="nav-inner1">
<div class="menu-bg"></div>
    <ul class="menu">
       <li class="first leaf grown-ups"><a href="/" title="" class="active">Grown-ups</a></li>    
       <li class="expanded store dropdown">
           <a href="https://store.highlights.com/" title="">Store</a>
           <div class="menu-bg">
           </div><ul class="menu">
              (More Nested menus with links under here)
```

I have tried many different ways of accessing the expanded store tab or the link nested underneath. My test is trying to just click on that tab to make sure it goes to the correct page Here is what seems to come the closest

```
@browser.div(:class => "nav-inner1").li(:class => "expanded store dropdown").click
```

This will highlight the correct tab, but it does not perform the click action, so the new page never loads.

How do i get this test to click the expanded store dropdown tab, or access the link nested within that tab by the click command?

Comment: When you click the tab, where do you expect to go? Is it the `https://store.highlights.com/` page?

Comment: That is the intended behavior Yes. I actually managed to solve the problem by just going further into the nested elements all the way to the <a href and just clicking on that. Should have noticed that way sooner than I did.

Comment: Thank you, i was wondering how to mark it resolved and wasnt aware I could post my own answer to complete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this with a bit further exploration. I just needed to go further into the nest to click on the proper element. Like so..

```
@browser.div(:class => "nav-inner1").li(:class => "expanded store dropdown").a(:index, 0).click
```

Comment: Note that `(:index, 0)` is implicitly included - ie you also do just `a.click`.